# Does http.nonProxyHosts support the subnet/CIDR IP syntax 172.16.0.0/12?

Tags: networking, proxy, tomcat, java

Does `http.nonProxyHosts` support the subnet/CIDR IP syntax `172.16.0.0/12` (private IP addresses)? The alternative would be quite complicated:

```
172.16.*\|172.17.*\|172.18.*\|172.19.*\|172.20.*\|172.21.*\|172.22.*\|172.23.*
```

...and so on, to not match `172.0.*` to `172.15.*` (with `172.*`) (or are these not important public IP addresses)?!

Actually I don't ask so specifically, but more generally. Because once you have understood the subnet/CIDR notation, you will want to use it!

Comment: BTW: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=blog